# Using django.contrib.auth, how can I let the user know why their login failed?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I need to display an error message on failed login attempts that says whether the user was inactive, the password was incorrect, or the user was not found. I'm authenticating against an API so I made a custom authentication backend. At the moment, to prove to the client login is working, I have it raising exceptions called UserNotFoundError, InactiveUserError, and InvalidPasswordError.

I'm fairly sure that's not the right way to go about it, and if I want to use Django's auth views I have no way to catch those exceptions anyway.

I assume I will need to create my own auth views. But, is there a better way?

*(I know it's not as secure to give a reason for a failed login, but I have to.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is totally untested, and not guaranteed to work, but you could try something along these lines. The only caveat with this solution is that your backend must be the last authentication backend used (or the only one used).

The contrib.auth.views.authenticate method takes an argument for authentication_form, meaning that you should be able to override it with your own form that extends contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm. That form is what calls your backend's authenticate() method. So, in your backend you could return some custom object which contains both the user instance as well as a "failed" status and a "failed reason" for why authentication failed.

If your custom object has a failed status, you can throw a ValidationError with the exception, at which point the login view will not do any further processing of the user.

Also make sure you override form.get_user() so that it returns the actual User instance, and not your custom object.

Comment: You could catch your custom exceptions in the overridden AuthenticationForm and re-raise them as ValidationErrors. Keep the returns and objects the same. It might be the only thing you need to change is the `clean()` method on AuthenticationForm where `authenticate()` is called. It won't matter which auth backends you use or their order.

Comment: @JCotton I think that's what I will do. I looked at the source and I figure since the `clean()` method raises an exception maybe it's fine for my backend to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Or just override login(), like such:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.views.decorators.debug import sensitive_post_parameters
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

# Avoid shadowing the login() and logout() views below.
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login as auth_login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.sites.models import get_current_site

# App specific
from axes.models import AccessAttempt


@sensitive_post_parameters()
@csrf_protect
@never_cache
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
          redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
          authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
          current_app=None, extra_context=None,
          form_name='form'):
    """
    Displays the login form and handles the login action.
    """
    redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name, '')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = authentication_form(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            netloc = urlparse.urlparse(redirect_to)[1]

            # Use default setting if redirect_to is empty
            if not redirect_to:
                redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

            # Heavier security check -- don't allow redirection to a different
            # host.
            elif netloc and netloc != request.get_host():
                redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

            # Okay, security checks complete. Log the user in.
            auth_login(request, form.get_user())

            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()

            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, _("Welcome <strong>%s</strong>.") % [request.user.get_full_name() if request.user.get_full_name() is not u"" else request.user.username].pop())

            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
        else:
            if extra_context is None:
                extra_context = {}
            extra_context.update({'login_form_errors': True})
            try:
                attempt = AccessAttempt.objects.get(ip_address=request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', ''))
                if attempt.failures_since_start < 2:
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, _(u"Invalid credentials, last chance."))
                if attempt.failures_since_start == 2:
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, _(u"Authentication has been blocked for a 24h cooldown period."))
            except AccessAttempt.DoesNotExist:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, _(u"Invalid credentials, please try again."))
    else:
        form = authentication_form(request)

    request.session.set_test_cookie()

    current_site = get_current_site(request)

    context = {
        form_name: form,
        redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
        }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
        current_app=current_app)
```

notes:

- this example uses django-axes
- it's bad practice to give a user specific errors on bad credentials for obvious security reasons